# How does setCharacterAttributes take account of '\n' and '\t'?

Tags: java, jtextpane

I am working in school project for creating a simple IDE.

In it I am processing the entire program as a single string like...

> ```
> import java.io.*\npublic class A{\n...........\0
> ```

To trace all

```
/*comments*/
"strings"
'c'haracters 
/**Documentation*/
```

I am maintaining an `ArrayList<Pair>` to mark all positions. Say, if (23,34) is an entry in `ArrayList<Pair> comments`, this means the characters between 23 and 34 are in a comment.
And I acheived that using **setCharacterAttributes** defined in **StyledDocument**.

My Questions are:

1. Does setCharacterAttributes interpret `\t` as one char or multiple spaces? Will it interpret end of line (`\n` ) as one position?
2. How is the replace argument used? (Though I saw the java documentation, I cannot make out the meaning of overrides).

Comment: I cleaned up your formatting and fixed the inconsistent spellings of the method name.  If you want the post to be indexed correctly you should be careful in spelling, at least the method names, even if your native language is not English.

Comment: @Jim Garrison Ya thank you really I felt difficult with spellings of charector and charecter even though I referred many times. Thank you. I will be careful next time when it comes to function name.

Comment: @JimGarrison The question is not related to programming. or else I will ask why it is charecter not charector? :-) But not interested to ask that in english.stackexchange.com to protect myself from downvotes:-)

Comment: It is `Character` -- you _can_ use copy/paste to copy method names into SO from your IDE.