# Could I use the DFA to trace strings of a certain Languages?

Tags: java, dfa

Generally DFA's are used to check, whether given string is present in a certain language.
e.g _ab1c is present in the Language of variables in C.

**What I am doing?**
But as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667150/how-does-setcharacterattributes-take-account-of-n-and-t),I am using DFA to trace all comments,strings etc.

**How I am doing?**
Consider an example of tracing a //comments in a given string/program.

```
static int makeTransition[][] = {
        /*     Transition Table        */
              /*{other,\n, \, /, *, ', "}  */  
            /*q0*/ { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
            /*q1*/ { 0, 0,-1, 2, 0, 0, 0},
            /*q2*/ { 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
        };
```

For this, If I have,

```
void assignPointerValuesInPairs(int index) 
    {
/*comments is an ArrayList
before marking start hotpointer = -1
after marking start hotpointer = 0
after marking end hotpointer is resetted to -1*/
        switch(currentState)
            {   
            case 2:     /*q2*/
                      comments.add(/*mark start*/);
                      hotPointer = 0;
                      break;
            case 0:    /*On initial state q0*/
                switch(hotPointer)
                {
                case 0: //If I am in end of comment.
                    comments.add(/*mark end*/);                            
                     hotPointer = -1; //Resetting the hotPointer.
                             break;

                case -1: /*Already in q1 only*/
                    /*Do nothing*/
                }
        }
     }

 public static void traceOut(String s) //entire program is accepted as string.
    {
            int index = 0;
        while (index < s.length() ) {                
                      char c = s.charAt(index);
                      try{
             currentState = makeTransition[currentState][symbolToInteger(c)];
              if(currentState == -1)
              throw new InvalidSyntaxException();
                  }
              catch(InvalidSyntaxException e){
              currentState = 0;
              invalidSyntax.add(index);                      
              }
                assignPointerValuesInPairs(index);
                index++;    
            }
                
                
                
                currentState = 0;
                assignPointerValuesInPairs(index);  //These 2 statements help to color while typing.. (i.e) It forces the current state to get finished abruptly.   
      }

}
```

My Question is...

can I use the DFA, to mark the end and start of the //comment in this way,
or I have to follow some other way like CFG etc..

i.e

> My Statement:  I can use DFA, not only to check for a particular language also to
> trace out certain strings belong to certain languages in a given
> string. (proof : by above method).
>
> Does my above statement correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Statement: I can use DFA, not only to check for a particular language also to trace out certain strings belong to certain languages in a given string.
>
> Does my above statement correct?

Your statement is trivially correct.  *Certain* languages *can* be checked using DFAs.
(The proof is by existence.  If *any* such language exists, then your statement is true.  And the language

```
        <program> ::= 'A'
```

is a trivial example to satisfy the existence proof.)

But this is not a particularly useful statement, because it says nothing about what *kind* of languages can be checked using a DFA.

For example, if your comment language supported nesting of comment blocks (as some historical programming languages have done), then a DFA won't work.

A second point that your statement ignores is whether use of a DFA is *practical* for a given language.  For a language with bounds on all forms of nesting / recursion in the grammar, etc you could in theory translate the grammar into a single finite DFA.  However the DFA would be so large that it would be unimplementable.

(Aside - no modern programming language has such bounds at the grammatical level ... not that this question is exclusively about *programming* languages.)

Comment: +1 for "However the DFA would be so large that it would be unimplementable." This line cleared my doubt.

Comment: I am having one more doubt. I already implemented in this way, as you said, my DFA is quite large. And I am writting a DFA to recognize keywords too. can I combine it in single DFA (states will be reduced)or can I write a seperate DFA for that(requires further more states). What I have to see? no.of.states or readability? –

Answer (score 0):

You need more states.  Your DFA breaks on multiline comments.  I'm pretty sure sure that you're not recognizing the "end of comment" sequence of `*/`.

And yes, a DFA can recognize these types of comments.  Easily.

Most common programming languages are not regular languages, and cannot be recognized by DFAs.  However, some are, and can be.

Comment: ya I done for all comments ,strings,chars,documentations with 11 states. But I provided a sample bcz to be precise. And does they recognise the /**Documentation*/ using CFG or by the above way.